# Will cell widgets inside QTableWidgets be deleted upon cleaning?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

Suppose I fill some cells of a `QTableWidget` with buttons:

```
ui->table->setCellWidget (i, 2, new QPushButton ("Details"));
```

Just a little bit later I scratch them all and do it again:

```
ui->table->clear();
```

Will this buttons get deleted automagically? Or do I need to store a list of them and delete manually? Also, Do I need to specify parent for every button like this: `QPushButton ("Details", ui->table)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table widget takes ownership of the widget. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) states this:

> Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell in the given row and column, *passing the ownership of the widget to the table.*

You also don't need to specify a parent on creation, that will be set by the tablewidget accordingly.

Comment: It should answer both? "tablewidget owns widget" means that it will delete it.

Comment: "tablewidget owns widget" means tablewidget will delete widget when tablewidget is deleted. This behavior comes from QObject AFAIK. The question was whether it will happen when `tablewidget->clear()` is called - tablewidget stays alive, but the table is cleansed.